# Issue with Vectors and custom classes in c++ with trivial constructor

Tags: c++, c, templates, vector

I am having an issue using vectors with a custom class that I am creating. Here is my code

```
vector<image> frames;


int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
  image tempImage;
  tempImage.read(fullname);
  frames.push_back(tempImage);
}
```

And the constructor for image is just image() {};

I am sure I am missing something simple, but I cannot figure out what it is. Here are my errors

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h:107:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'image'
  { ::new(__p) _Tp(__val); }
               ^   ~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:604:20: note: in instantiation of member function
  '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<image>::construct' requested here
        this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_finish, __x);
                      ^
video.cpp:50:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<image, std::allocator<image> >::push_back'
  requested here
            frames.push_back(tempImage);
                   ^
./image.h:25:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const image') would lose const qualifier
image(image &img);
^
./image.h:24:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
image();
^
In file included from video.cpp:1:
In file included from ./video.h:6:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector:73:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/vector.tcc:252:8: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'image'
      _Tp __x_copy = __x;
          ^          ~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:608:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<image,
  std::allocator<image> >::_M_insert_aux' requested here
      _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
      ^
video.cpp:50:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<image, std::allocator<image> >::push_back'
  requested here
            frames.push_back(tempImage);
                   ^
./image.h:25:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const value_type' (aka 'const image')) would
  lose const qualifier
image(image &img);
^
./image.h:24:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
image();
^
./image.h:26:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
image(int rows, int columns);
^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Must be a typo in your image class. Could you please share its declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are supplying a reference `&` in your copy constructor:

```
image(const image& other);
```

It seems, you might be passing by const value instead.

If `image` is just a trivial class, try removing all forms of constructors; the automatically generated ones should work fine.

Comment: Actually, no (I thought the same first): the copy constructor is defined with a non-`const` reference.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The implicit one will be created as a non-const reference, but it is acceptable to have it as a const-reference (but not by value).  C++11, 12.8.2

Comment: @Zac “it’s acceptable” – yes, but not in OP’s use-case. And the error message says *explicitly* that this is the cause here. `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<image>::construct` tries and fails to invoke `T(T const&)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, sorry, I thought you were talking in general here.  My mistake.

Comment: Hmm, still waiting for Red to update the question...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11, I recommend calling the constructor explicitly via `image tempImage{};`. Otherwise, you're while loop is an infinite one, since you never increment `i`.

Alternatively, you can try removing explicitly your default constructor and let the compiler synthesize one for you to see what happens.

Comment: `image tempImage{};` and `image tempImage;` are the same for a user defined type.

Answer (score 0):

`image` must have a copy constructor.  The C++11 standard (Section 12.8) defines what those can look like:

```
class X
{
public:
    X(); // default constructor

    X(const X& x); // const-reference copy constructor
    X(X& x); // non-const copy constructor
    X(volatile X& x); // volatile reference copy constructor
    X(const volatile X& x); // const volatile reference copy constructor
    X(const X& x, int i = 0); // can use any of the above with defaulted values as well
};
```

If you defined a move-constructor, but not a copy-constructor, an implicit copy-constructor will not be created for you (nor will the copy-assignment operator be created implicitly) unless you defined a copy-assignment operator as well.

If you take a closer look at the following part of the error:

> ./image.h:25:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument
>   ('const image') would lose const qualifier image(image &img);

It appears you have declared an (invalid) copy constructor as `image(const image)`, but are trying to pass a nonconst-reference to it.  Change your copy constructor declaration to `image(const image&)` and that will likely fix this issue.

Alternatively, if you have the copy constructor and copy assignment operator declared as private/protected, you will get similar errors (that is, you made your class non-copyable).  In order to hold any object `X` in an STL container, `X` must be copyable (which is why you couldn't put `auto_ptr` in a container)

Comment: The first bit doesn't sound right: defining a (non-copy) constructor would not affect the compiler generated constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza Posted that before lunch and it isn't conveying what I wanted it to ... I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to implement a copy constructor?  i.e. Image(const Image& _other);